# Split() function isn't giving output

Tags: c#, asp.net

Whats wrong in the code..? It isn't working!!

Actually I want to split the entries from one of the field of database.. The items in it are separated by commas..

Here is what I am doing.

```
string str = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ingredients"].ToString();

string[] split = str.Split(',');
IList<string> lblListItemIngredients  = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in split)
{
  lblListItemIngredients.Add(item);
}
```

and in my aspx page,

```
<ul>
<li>
<asp:label id="lblListItemIngredients" runat="server></asp:Label>
</li>
</ul>
```

But the output isn't coming, but in debugging mode, i can see the string is splitting.. Whats wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You're adding the strings to an `IList<string>`, but on the page you have a label with the same name as the list. Rename the `IList<string> reference` for a start then access the label using `lblListItemIngredients.Text`...

Comment: You're also mis-matching a quote in your `runat` .... `<asp:label id="lblListItemIngredients" runat="server></asp:Label>`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the data in the list to the control somehow. That doesn't happen magically just because you give a variable the same name as the id of the control.

Actually, you should use a different name for the variable, otherwise it will shadow the property that has been added to the page object.

If you want to make a HTML list it's not enough to put a label in one list item, that won't create one list item for each string. You can use a repeater:

```
<ul>
  <asp:Repeater id="lblListItemIngredients" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <li><%# Container.DataItem %></li>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</ul>
```

You don't have to create a list for a data source, an array works just fine:

```
string str = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ingredients"].ToString();
string[] split = str.Split(',');

lblListItemIngredients.DataSource = split;
lblListItemIngredients.DataBind();
```

Comment: With all due respect, you do not *have* to use the list as the control's data source. Adding the items iteratively is legitimate, but the OP is simply not doing it correctly.

Comment: @DavidW: Yes, you are right. I have changed the wording to focus on the problem instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an `asp:label` control in your page markup when you should be using something like an `asp:ListBox`.  Eliminate the `IList<String>` declaration from your code as well.

A better way to add an array of strings to a ListBox would merely be as follows:

First, in your markup, change the improper control reference to a ListBox:

```
    <asp:ListBox id="IngredientList" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

Secondly, in the source, streamline the addition:

```
    string str = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ingredients"].ToString();

    string[] ingredients= str.Split(',');
    IngredientList.Items.AddRange(ingredients);
```

This method eliminates the incorrect label control in the markkup, and from the code behind eliminates the manual iteration and the unneeded IList declaration in the original version. Hope this helps.

Comment: A downvote? What on earth for? The courtesy of an explanation for the downvote is requested. IF there is something wrong with what's been posted that I have overlooked, I'd like to have the chance to correct it.

Comment: The markup from a ListBox is nothing like what the OP was after, ie it doesn't produce an HTML list.

Comment: It wasn't at all clear *what* the OP wanted, as it produced no output, and contained errors that indicated the OP was not sure how to emit a list of items *of any form* and made *no* indication that a series of `<li>` objects was his objective. A listbox is a perfectly legitimate way to illustrate a correct way of emitting a list of items, and I noted that the OP should be using something *like* a ListBox as a container. I respectfully submit your downvote is unjustified.

Comment: In the nicest possible way, don't take it personally :-) I wasn't saying that your answer was wrong,  I only wanted to say what I said, and that's been done now. 

It seems I cannot remove my -1 unless you edit the answer, as my vote is currently locked.

Comment: @DD59 Done is done, I guess. Just frustrating to lose rep in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Guffa is bang-on already, but just for completeness, and because it is in keeping with the spirit of how you are were doing it in the first place :-)

if you updated your mark up to:

```
   <ul>
   <asp:Literal id="literalIngredients" runat="server" />
   </ul>
```

(To be honest your original code would have more or less worked  if inside your foreach loop you used `yourLabel.Text += item;`, as Guffa said, it is not really a good idea to call the variable and the control the same name)

and updated your code to

```
    string str = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Ingredients"].ToString();

    string[] split = str.Split(',');
    // not needed IList<string> lblListItemIngredients  = new List<string>();
    foreach (string item in split)
    {
      literalIngredients.Text += string.Format("<li>{0}</li>",item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should be using asp:ListBox instead of Label

Comment: +1 to offset what appears to be a pointless downvote w/no explanation.